# How to test a facebook "test app"

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Referring to the "test app" feature detailed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

Our production app is here; it is a Magento store in an iframe.
https://www.facebook.com/lennonandmaisystella/app_1559271704291834

I created a "test app" for it, and set it to pull the page tab from our development server instead of the production one.
Now I can't figure out what URL I would go to to see the test app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add the Test App as separate App on the Page. It would then be reachable with its Test App ID: https://www.facebook.com/lennonandmaisystella/app_{Test-App-ID}

You just have to add the Page Tab platform to the Test App too, and fill in the URL of your dev server. But you did that already, according to your description.

Comment: That did it.The hard part was figuring out how to add the test app page to the existing facebook page. I did this by going to 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=<my app id>&redirect_uri=<my tab url>

Then it allowed me to pick a page to add it to.